# Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Error from component that doesn't use Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing a simple application that fetches some products from an API and displays them in a table.

I have got a Fetcher component that fetches the data from the API and a Records functional component that using Elastic UI is meant to display the records in a table. The issue occurs in the Records component but I can't seem to figure out why. I will paste my code below. I am not even using a hook inside the Records component so I don't know why that error occurs. If I return a simple paragraph instead of the Elastic Table the error disappears.

```
import React from "react";
import {
EuiBasicTable,
EuiLink,
EuiHealth,
} from '@elastic/eui';

const Records = (props) => {
const records = props.records
const columns = [
    {
        field: 'firstName',
        name: 'First Name',
        sortable: true,
        'data-test-subj': 'firstNameCell',
        mobileOptions: {
            render: item => (
                <span>
                    {item.firstName}{' '}
                    <EuiLink href="#" target="_blank">
                        {item.lastName}
                    </EuiLink>
                </span>
            ),
            header: false,
            truncateText: false,
            enlarge: true,
            fullWidth: true,
        },
    },
    {
        field: 'lastName',
        name: 'Last Name',
        truncateText: true,
        render: name => (
            <EuiLink href="#" target="_blank">
                {name}
            </EuiLink>
        ),
        mobileOptions: {
            show: false,
        },
    },
    {
        field: 'github',
        name: 'Github',
    },
    {
        field: 'online',
        name: 'Online',
        dataType: 'boolean',
        render: online => {
            const color = online ? 'success' : 'danger';
            const label = online ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
            return <EuiHealth color={color}>{label}</EuiHealth>;
        },
    },
];
const getRowProps = item => {
    const { id } = item;
    return {
        'data-test-subj': `row-${id}`,
        className: 'customRowClass',
        onClick: () => console.log(`Clicked row ${id}`),
    };
};

const getCellProps = (item, column) => {
    const { id } = item;
    const { field } = column;
    return {
        className: 'customCellClass',
        'data-test-subj': `cell-${id}-${field}`,
        textOnly: true,
    };
};
return <>
    <EuiBasicTable
        items={records}
        rowHeader="firstName"
        columns={columns}
        rowProps={getRowProps}
        cellProps={getCellProps} />
</>

}

export default Records;
```

I will also paste the code for the Fetcher component from which I render the above component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Records from './Records'


const Fetcher = () => {
const [records, setRecords] = useState([{}])
let getToken = () => {
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        body: "grant_type=password&username=" + email + "&password=" + password
    };
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://spaces.nexudus.com/api/token', 
options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            if (response.access_token !== null && response.access_token !== undefined) {
                getProducts(response.access_token)
            }
        }
        )
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

let getProducts = (access_token) => {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
        }
    };

    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://spaces.nexudus.com/api/billing/products?page=1&size=25', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            if (response.Records.length > 0) {
                setRecords(response.Records)
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

useEffect(() => {
    getToken()
}, [])
return <>
    <Records records={records}></Records>
</>
}

export default Fetcher;
```

Comment: How do you use `Fetcher`?

Comment: I am just rendering it from the App main component <Fetcher></Fetcher> @KonradLinkowski